# Not able to print value using echo

Tags: ios, xcode, run-script

I am using Run Script in Xcode, I am facing some problem

I am declaring variable like below

```
URL1 = "/Users/UserName/Desktop/Folder/13072012/libRestKit.a"
```

And below i am printing it echo `"Test $URL1 Test"` I tried like this also `"Test ${URL1} Test"`

I am not able to print the `URL1` value, below i use this

`echo "Hello, world!"`
and i am able to print this, I am new to scripting What is the problem can any one help me out

Comment: Have you started the script with `#!/bin/sh`?  Have you made it executable?  What does the Xcode log show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try without spaces:

```
URL1="/Users/UserName/Desktop/Folder/13072012/libRestKit.a"
```

Putting spaces around `=` is a common error when using bash and other shells of the same family.